# Connecting JSON API for parsing

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am looking to parse the following page and extract every instance of a name. http://api.openparliament.ca/politicians/.

I have been following this guide for reference: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/ However when it runs, there is nothing returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'api.openparliament.ca/politicians/?format=json', true);
request.onload = function () {

  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(politicians => {
      console.log(politicians.name);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
}

request.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Sean to StackOverflow.

Well, first of all you have some issues in your code.

- Add the **http://** in the URL in this line: `request.open('GET', 'http://api.openparliament.ca/politicians/?format=json', true);`.
- You need to wait for [**`XMLHttpRequest.readyState`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) is **`DONE`**. In your code you can check the readyState property in this way:

---

```
if (request.readyState === 4) {
    // Code goes here...
}
```

---

- Check if the `XMLHttpRequest` has returned a 200 status code. You can do in this way:

---

```
if (request.status === 200) {
    // Code goes here...
}
```

---

Then with the previous code you can do:

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
```

Where **`data`** is an object that it has two properties: **`objects`** and **`pagination`** where **`objects`** is an array of objects and **`pagination`** is an object.

Then you can do:

```
data.objects.forEach(politician => {
  console.log(politician.name);
});
```

Here is the complete demo:

```js
(function() {

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://api.openparliament.ca/politicians/?format=json', true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
      if (request.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        data.objects.forEach(politician => {
          console.log(politician.name);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    }
  }

  request.send();
}());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Danny, sorry for the delayed reply as I didn't know how to comment. I very much appreciate the time you put in to explain to me the process.